# Get list of node dependencies

Tags: 6, nodes

in Drupal 6, is there a way to list by programmation (function or SQL code) the dependancies of a node ?

For exemple, I have videos that are nodes. Thoses videos are refered in other nodes. Before deleting the video I need to update the nodes which refer it. 
I have the module "Node Dependencies" that lists the dependencies of a node in the UI, but I need to get this list with code.

Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal does not know "dependencies" on it's own, so I assume it's something provided by the module you named. Yes, it is possible. After all that module is doing exactly this. Just read it's code and see, PHP is an interpreted language after all. [It seems there is no module with that exact name on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/search/site/node%20dependencies?f%5B0%5D=ss_meta_type%3Amodule), so I can't provide more detailed instruction now. To find it yourself, you need:

1. Find implementation of hook_menu() in this module
2. Locate entry for GUI page that shows what you want
3. Find implementation of a function that obtains data for that GUI page

Comment: Thanks, I looked in the module, and indeed, it isn't an official one. I think I'll be able to reuse its code. I hoped there would be an "official" way to do this, but it's not the case :)